# What is the OpenCL-equivalent of gpu::reduce()? (OpenCV 2.4)

Tags: opencv

I want to rewrite my nVIDIA-enabled code and its `gpu::` functions as OpenCL-enabled code. I can't find an `ocl::reduce()` function on [OCL's Matrix reductions](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/ocl/doc/matrix_reductions.html) to do a row sum, akin to [`gpu::reduce()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/gpu/doc/matrix_reductions.html#gpu-reduce). Any ideas?

Comment: I thought that if you passed `UMat` to [`reduce`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=reduce#void reduce(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int dim, int rtype, int dtype)) that it would just work or am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. I'm a bit reticent to use any `cv::` functions as I presume they only run on the CPU compared to `ocl::` functions that run on the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenCL is a pretty basic language and does not provide that much high level functions you may need to write the Kernel etc. by yourself.

You may want to check this answer:

[Reduction of matrix rows in OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384542/reduction-of-matrix-rows-in-opencl)